# What's better? To hide with css or to add with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a best practices question.

I have a check mark icon that I want to show only if an item has been selected.

My standard practice is to include the icon in the HTML and hide by default with CSS. Then I use jQuery to show/hide the icon based on the conditions.

Is this the best way? Or is it better to not include the icon in the HTML to start, and instead use jQuery to append or remove the icon as needed?

By "better" I suppose I mean performance and usability. And I should add that I'm not considering the css-only :checked pseudo class as a solution here, as that doesn't apply to my particular situation.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: It depends upon what you want to optimize.  For bandwidth, jQuery is awfully large to hide a check mark.  But if you are using it already anyways...

Comment: CSS is probably better but yeah...it depends.

Comment: CSS is probably cleaner in this case. Especially if have more of such use cases.

Comment: Hiding and showing is the usual way it's done, either by calling `hide/show/toggle` or by toggling a class. It simplifies the code, because event binding is simpler and you don't need code to construct all the HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks for the input, all. It sounds like toggling a class to show/hide with css is better than "creating" and appending the icon with jquery each time. That was my assumption, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: Performance isn't really an issue here, I don't think that using jquery to add/remove a node from the DOM is going to break the bank for anyone. I would rather see the element in the html source so I have some indication of what's happening but honestly, it doesn't really matter. Do whatever is most consistent with current practices for the project.

Comment: Good point about seeing the element in the html source.

Comment: There's a common philosophy: Use HTML for structure, JS for behavior. Keep the HTML as static as possible.

Comment: Consider how the site would look with CSS disabled.   Then again with JS disabled.   Then again with both disabled.     With css off, the image will always show if its in source code.   with js off, it can't be turned on.    Which is worse?  that's for your application needs to decide.

Comment: you don't have to use jQuery to hide and show, if thats the only thing you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would reword this to make this not opinion based other than to just ask "how do I hide/show an icon" which is unnecessary since that question has been answered before -- so I suppose the question should be closed. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I would add the icon to the DOM and hide by default using CSS. If I am already using jQuery in my site then would gladly use it to toggle but if not then I would not introduce it just for this function alone but rather create my own small foundation namespace and add utility methods to it.

> Generally speaking adding / removing DOM elements is slower than
>   showing or hiding with or without jQuery.